# How to pass UserCreationForm inside another built-in view (like FormView)

Tags: django, django-forms

As a beginner, I am trying to skim through the Django documentation.

In order to allow a user to register, I want to create a register view.

Now, I have seen many examples on how to do this with a function-based view which passes the built-in [`UserCreationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm).

What I am trying to do is to take advantages of all the built-in views, so I was wondering if is possible to pass the `UserCreationForm` inside, let's say, the built-in `FormView`.

At the moment I have managed to render the form at the required URL, but once submitted, it doesn't create the user even though it redirects me to the home page (as wanted).

How can I fix this?

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView


class RegisterView(FormView):
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = '/home/'
```

And here my html

```
{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'home' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.password1.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.password1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.password2.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.password2 }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

If it can be of any use, this are my settings:

```
"""
Django settings for my_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'skqmec#*-cflm(s-%3rj&-1ti&ayk)%$ihk5h$3$u=0)ym!&+s'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # created apps

    'person',
    'accounts',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my_project/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'persons/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'accounts/templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my_project.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y']
DATE_FORMAT = ['%d-%m-%Y']

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/my_project/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have managed to make this work.

Basically my original code was right, the only thing I had to change was the model form which the `RegisterView` I have defined inherits.

It doesn't work as a subclass of the `FormView` but has to be a subclass of the `CreateView`.

If someone could explain to me why in the comments that would be helpful :)

The answer I have found comes from [here](https://wsvincent.com/django-user-authentication-tutorial-signup/).

ps. Also, I had to `reverse_lazy` the successful URL.

Answer (score 0):

**@Mirko Oricci**,

You did not save the form values to db. That's why it redirects to the success_url without saving the data.

You need to save it. So you should use **form_valid** method to save the form values.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView


class RegisterView(FormView):
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = '/home/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()  // form data will be saved
        return super(RegisterView, self).form_valid(form)
```

## Please change the registration.html form action

```
{% block content %} 


{% if form.errors %} {% for field in form %} {% for error in field.errors %}
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
     <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
  </div>
{% endfor %} {% endfor %}{% endif %}

  <form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
   {% csrf_token %}
  <table>

   <tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
   </tr>

  <tr>
  <td>{{ form.password1.label_tag }}</td>
  <td>{{ form.password1 }}</td>
  <td>{{ form.password2.label_tag }}</td>
  <td>{{ form.password2 }}</td>
</tr>

</table>

<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>



{% endblock %}
```

in **urls.py** create a router path:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import RegisterView
urlpatterns = [
       path('', RegisterView.as_view(), name='register')
   ]
```

I have checked and also i am getting the new user in admin panel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your solution (which makes sense), but when I check on the admin site, and I click on the 'Users' link, the new user is not created

Comment: @MirkoOricci, I have edited the code and also checked properly at my end. its working. Please have a check at your end.

Comment: @ Iqbal Hussain, I have just copied and pasted all the code you have written, but when I check in the admin the only user I have got is the admin itself. I don't know why is not working. Might be something in the settings? I have no idea...

Comment: **@MirkoOricci**, Have you created the route in urls.py and also have you changed the form action to the viewmethod which is defined as a router **name='register'** in the urls.py file. so form action will be **<form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">**

Comment: yes, first I have done the changes manually first, and then I have copied and pasted all the code you have written just to avoid any possible mistake, but still doesn't work

Comment: I am wondering if UserCreationForm comes with validation because I have realized that I can add two different passwords and it doesn't display any error once submitted. I am saying this, as I checked in venv/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py and the class UserCreationForm defines a clean_password2 method which is supposed to raise an error.

Comment: @MirkoOricci, I have edited the code to show the error message. Now you may get confirm for why its not saving.

Comment: Thanks. I have done some research and I think the problem was that while a FormView just displays a form and validate it, a Create view does exactly the same but also saves the object created. So, everything is working now. My question now is: 'What is a FormView good for, if it just displays a form without saving objects in automatic?' I guess that for cases in which you want to customise the save method, but at the moments that's beyond my understanding of Django :)